# Jerky scroll animation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I work on this website https://staging.sophiepeirano.com/fr/ and unfortuunately, the scroll is jerky on chrome but not in firefox
How to correct the bug on chrome ? It's front JS files so you can help me

I tried to use pure JS instead of jQuery on the first element but nothing changed

```
<script>
                $=jQuery;
        //$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
                        var ScrollVal = $(document).scrollTop();
            if(ScrollVal < window.innerWidth) {

                //$('[data-scroll-id=content]').css({'left': '-'+ScrollVal+"px", 'top': ''+ScrollVal+"px"});
                //$('[data-scroll-id=content]').css('top', ''+ScrollVal+"px");
               var dsid = document.querySelector("[data-scroll-id=content]");
                            dsid.style.left = '-'+ScrollVal+"px";
                            dsid.style.top = ''+ScrollVal+"px";
            }
            else if(ScrollVal >= window.innerWidth && ScrollVal < window.innerWidth*2+$('[data-scroll-id=presentation] > *').height()) {
                relativeScroll = ScrollVal-window.innerWidth;
                $('[data-scroll-id=content]').css('left', '-'+window.innerWidth+"px");
                $('[data-scroll-id=content]').css('top', ''+ScrollVal+"px");
                $('[data-scroll-id=presentation] > *').css('marginTop', '-'+(relativeScroll/2)+"px")
            }
            else if (ScrollVal >= window.innerWidth*2+$('[data-scroll-id=presentation] > *').height() && ScrollVal < (window.innerWidth*3+$('[data-scroll-id=presentation] > *').height())) {
                console.log('the 3')
                relScroll = ScrollVal-(window.innerWidth*2+$('[data-scroll-id=presentation] > *').height())
                $('[data-scroll-id=content]').css('top', ''+ScrollVal+"px");
                $('[data-scroll-id=content]').css('left', '-'+window.innerWidth-relScroll+"px");
            }
            else if (ScrollVal >= (window.innerWidth*3+$('[data-scroll-id=presentation] > *').height()) && ScrollVal < (window.innerWidth*3+$('[data-scroll-id=presentation] > *').height()+$('[data-scroll-id=services] > *').height())) {
                console.log('the 4')
                relScroll = ScrollVal-(window.innerWidth*2+$('[data-scroll-id=presentation] > *').height()+window.innerWidth)
                $('[data-scroll-id=content]').css('top', ''+ScrollVal+"px");
                $('[data-scroll-id=content]').css('left', '-'+window.innerWidth*2+"px");
                $('[data-scroll-id=services] > *').css('marginTop', '-'+(relScroll/2)+"px")
            }
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not exactly fluid in my Firefox either. Without more specifics about which part of code exactly "jerks" I would bet about performance issues. For example jQuery calls are easy to write because it's short, but it's easy to forget that they are function calls that search all the DOM tree. All calls like `$(document)`, `$('[data-scroll-id=content]')` can be stored in vatiables _outside_ of the event handler, that will save quite some computing. Also, sorry for being direct, this scroll layout is an interesting coding exercise but I don't find it easy to read (just my opinion)

Comment: (part 2) ... maybe it's just some fine tuning to find about the point the lateral sections start to arrive fron the side, like adding empty spaces for transitions, but when they start to appear, truncated sections are hard to read or impossible. Maybe ease-and-out functions could help, I don't know